# Best way to clear pubsub subscription?

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I had an edge case show up and some messages are stuck in a loop of trying to be pulled and failing at parsing. How can I get rid of all these messages? I tried --auto-ack with the gcloud command (`gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull <SUBSCRIPTION> --auto-ack`), but they are still showing up.

any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

`--auto-ack` should work unless your subscriber is actively running and therefore possibly holding on to those messages, i.e., the [acknowledgement deadline](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/subscriber#create) has not passed. In this case, the messages are not delivered to the `gcloud` tool because your subscriber is holding on to them. You have a couple of options:

1. Shut down your subscriber, wait until the ack deadline has passed, and then run the `gcloud` command you specified. The messages in question should then be received by the command-line tool and acknowledged. The command does print out the messages it receives. You may also want to set the `--max-messages` option as it defaults to 1.
2. Update your subscriber to handle these messages that cannot be parsed. You could decide to acknowledge them or you could create a separate topic for such messages, publish the failed messages to that topic, and then acknowledge the messages. That way, you can still inspect the messages on this different topic (with a different subscriber/subscription) without impeding your main subscriber. This is commonly known as a [dead letter queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_letter_queue).

Comment: If you are using the gcloud command line tool the argument to enable more than 1 message at the time is now --limit. Eg.
    gcloud pubsub subscription pull --auto-ack --limit 1000 projects/<project name>/subscriptions/<subscription name>

Comment: what's subscriber?Is background cloud function a subscriber?